# Why clang does not replace this loop with a memmove

Tags: c, clang

Consider this memcpy similar function:

```
void copy(unsigned *restrict const dst, unsigned const *restrict const src, unsigned long n)
{
    for (unsigned long x = 0; x < n; ++x)
    {
        dst[x] = src[x];
    }
}
```

<kbd>[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aEGGE56zK)</kbd>

This code get optimised nicely to a memcpy:

```
copy:
        cbz     x2, .L1
        lsl     x2, x2, 2
        b       memcpy
.L1:
        ret
```

However, when I remove `restrict`, `clang` applies loop vectorisation and [does not replace](https://godbolt.org/z/E3nzzdraq) it with a `memmove`. Why is that?

I tried to compile this with optimisation report enabled:

```
clang-10 main.c -c -O3 -fsave-optimization-record -S && cat ./main.opt.yaml
```

And this is what I got with `restrict`:

```
--- !Passed
Pass:            loop-idiom
Name:            ProcessLoopStoreOfLoopLoad
DebugLoc:        { File: main.c, Line: 4, Column: 12 }
Function:        copy
Args:
  - String:          'Formed a call to '
  - NewFunction:     llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64
  - String:          '() function'
...
```

and w/o `restrict`:

```
--- !Passed
Pass:            loop-vectorize
Name:            Vectorized
DebugLoc:        { File: main.c, Line: 3, Column: 3 }
Function:        copy
Args:
  - String:          'vectorized loop (vectorization width: '
  - VectorizationFactor: '4'
  - String:          ', interleaved count: '
  - InterleaveCount: '2'
  - String:          ')'
...
```

The optimiser goes straight to loop vectorisation skipping `ProcessLoopStoreOfLoopLoad` with no message printed. Why is that? Why can't this code be replaced with `memmove`?

Comment: If `src` and `dest` overlap, then the loop may end up copying some of the newly copied `dest` values back into `dest`, which `memmove` won't do.  For example, if `dest == src +1`, the loop will replicate `src[0]` over and over.

Comment: Isn't this the entire point of the `restrict` keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is about the observable effects of the operation while you have collision between the arrays.
For instance:

```
1 2 3 4
```

If src points to 1 and dst points to 2 the result should be

```
1 1 1 1
```

Memmove on the other hand, in case of an overlap does this:

> The memory areas may overlap: copying takes place as though the bytes in src are first copied into a temporary array that does not overlap src or dest, and the bytes are
> then copied from the temporary array to dest.

I.e the result of such copy would be:

```
1 1 2 3
```

what differs significantly from the original code.

Also, if you write this memmove similar code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void copy(unsigned *const dst, unsigned const *const src, unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned *tmp = malloc(n * sizeof(*tmp));
    for (unsigned long x = 0; x < n; ++x)
    {
        tmp[x] = src[x];
    }

    for (unsigned long x = 0; x < n; ++x)
    {
        dst[x] = tmp[x];
    }

    free(tmp);
}
```

`clang` would nicely replace it with a `memmove`:

```
copy:                                   # @copy
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        je      .LBB0_2
        pushq   %rax
        shlq    $2, %rdx
        callq   memmove@PLT
        addq    $8, %rsp
.LBB0_2:
        retq
```

<kbd>[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q6b5edoqK)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't this code be replaced with memmove?

It is the other way round: `memmove()` is optimized into a **vectorized loop**.

So `memmcpy()` is fastest, SIMD second and `memmove()` third choice.

(Tested on gcc which seems to do quite the same as clang in OP.)

The combination 2x`restrict` plus `memmove` leads to `memcpy`. It is all a question of possible overlap.

Comment: I don't think `memmove` was optimised. Otherwise I'd see this in the optimisation report.